# checkbox checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript

```
function Check_Clickd_li(objRef) {
    var btn1 = $find("<%= RadButton1.ClientID %>");
    var btn2 = $find("<%= RadButton2.ClientID %>");                
    if (objRef.checked = true) {
        btn1.set_enabled(true);
        btn2.set_enabled(true);
        alert("Enable");
    }
    else if (objRef.checked = false) {
        btn1.set_enabled(false);
        btn2.set_enabled(false);
        alert("Disable");
    }
}
```

What is the problem in this code? It always says "Enable".

Comment: First please be clear in the syntax of javascript bro

Answer (score 4):

You're doing an assignment. Use == for a comparison, or just:

```
if (objRef.checked) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `==` for comparison (or just test `if(objRef.checked)`).

Right now you **set** the value to `true`...